# How to replace value while grouping with specific one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe:

```
id     type     val   
a1      q       100
a1      v       4
a1      l       17
b1      p       1
b1      j       700
b1      s       3
```

I want to group by id with keeping column type and summing values in column val. Value in column type must be one with highest val. So desired result must be:

```
id     type     val   
a1      q       121
b1      j       704
```

Type for id a1 is q cause it had highest val (100) and b1 is j cause it had highest val (700). How to do that?

Comment: In future questions, please include sample data in working code, so it's easy for people to take your example and provide an answer. Having it in text sure beats having an image, but defining the dataframe in code helps to provide working code in an answer that will meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
df.sort_values(by='val', ascending=False).groupby('id').agg({'type': 'first', 'val': 'sum'})
```

It gives:

```
   type  val
id          
a1    q  121
b1    j  704
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df_max = df.groupby(['id']).agg({'val': 'max'})[['id', 'type']]

df_sum = df.groupby(['id']).agg({'val': 'sum'})

df_sum.merge(df_max, on='id', how='left')
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is what you're after:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a1', 'q', 100],
    ['a1', 'v', 4],
    ['a1', 'l', 17],
    ['b1', 'p', 1],
    ['b1', 'j', 700],
    ['b1', 's', 3]
])
df.columns = ['id', 'type', 'val']

print(df.loc[df.groupby('id')['val'].idxmax()])
```

Result:

```
   id type  val
0  a1    q  100
4  b1    j  700
```

By the way, you say "must be the highest value" but in your desired output, it's actually the *sum* of those values.

If the sum is the desired result, this might meet your needs:

```py
result = df.loc[df.groupby('id')['val'].idxmax()]
result.set_index('id', inplace=True)
result['val'] = df.groupby('id')['val'].sum()
```

Result:

```
   type  val
id          
a1    q  121
b1    j  704
```

Note that the name of the `val` column might now be confusing, depending on the actual application, as it is no longer the `val`, but really the `sum(val)` or `val_sum`, etc.

Comment: it didn't sum values in column val

Comment: The _type_ is from the corresponding highest value, while the `val` column is the sum of the group `id`

Answer (score 0):

In your case

```
out = df.set_index('type').groupby('id').val.agg(['sum','idxmax']).reset_index()
   id  sum idxmax
0  a1  121      q
1  b1  704      j
```